# Why will STA thread "leak small amounts of memory" if it fails to dispatch Windows messages?

Tags: windows, winapi, com

After carefully reading [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/136885) I noticed an interesting statement there. The article says that if I have an STA thread and that thread doesn't dispatch Windows messages then that thread

- will be unable to receive COM events form a COM server
- can cause message broadcasters to hang (and thus sometimes cause a deadlock)
- ***surprisingly...*** *will leak small amounts of memory*

While the first two statements are rather reasonable - Windows messages are used for dispatching COM calls to objects in single-threaded apartments - I don't get the third one at all.

Why exactly will a thread "*leak small amounts of memory*" if it doesn't dispatch Windows messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages that you're failing to dispatch - they must be queued up *somewhere*, waiting for that fateful moment at which you'll finally start dispatching them. That queue is going to use some memory.

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine because that a struct is allocated, and posted with the message.
If the message is not processed, the struct containing the message parameters will not be freed.